# Passing second parameter to find() function

Tags: javascript

Given a function:

`const UseColor = (name) => colors.brand.find(c => c.shade === name).color`

that loops over an array of objects with hex values. Given multiple arrays of objects, how can I pass a second parameter, so that I can have a `type` parameter dynamically passed to the `.find()` method?:

`const UseColor = (type, name) => color.type.find(c => c.shade === name).color`

Comment: `color[type].find(...)`

Comment: Ah! I was forgetting to remove the `.`after color! If you post this as an answer, I'll mark it as such. Thanks!

Comment: The question is already closed as a duplicate of a question that shows how to do it. I was just saving you the trouble of reading it.

Comment: You don't just remove the `.`, you add `[` and `]` around the variable.